# Camera turning on when plugging in headset

Tags: windows-10, webcam, headset

I have a Predator Helios 300 laptop and a Mpow Air Pro headset.

My headset works just fine on my desktop, but for some reason when I plug it into my laptop it turns on the camera. This is obviously a little creepy and I was wondering how to stop it and what is causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As instructed in the below article that this is expected behavior for some Acer models and could be resolved by turning off the Waves NX functionality.

***Camera activates automatically when speakers or headphones are connected***
[https://au.answers.acer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/58472/~/camera-activates-automatically-when-speakers-or-headphones-are-connected](https://au.answers.acer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/58472/%7E/camera-activates-automatically-when-speakers-or-headphones-are-connected)